# Output XML file will not display properly in a browser

Tags: xml, powershell

I get a display error when using `$xmlwriter`.

The XML document outputs and I can view it using either notepad ++ or open office, but it will not display correctly using IE, Chrome, or Firefox. When trying Firefox I get the following output:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location: file:///C:file.xml
>   Line Number 2, Column 26:

Then the entire header, but none of the elements created underneath.

I have isolated the issue to adding the following to the initial (root) element:

```
$xmlwriter.WriteElementString("Security Token","red") 
$xmlwriter.WriteAttributeString("Security Token","blue")
```

Either of these will result in the output file not displaying in a browser, whereas without this it does.

I used https://techhelpguy.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/57/ as a resource for this.

My code looks like this:

```
$filepath = c:\whereiamputtingthis.xml

$xmlwriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($filepath,$null)
$xmlwriter.formatting = "Indented"
$xmlwriter.indentation = "4"

$xmlwriter.WriteStartDocument()    

$XSLproptext = "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'"

$xmlwriter.writeprocessinginstruction("xml-stylesheet",$xlproptext)    

$xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("data1","websitehere")
$xmlwriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","xsi","websitehere","website2here")    

$xmlwriter.writestartelement("reportData")
$xmlwriter.WriteElementString("Security Token","red")
$xmlwriter.WriteAttributeString("Security Token","blue")    

$xmlwriter.writeendelement() #reportdata
$xmlwriter.writeendelement() #data1
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()

$xmlwriter.flush()
$xmlwriter.close()
```

There is no `$xmlwriter.finalize` as this is not recognised in the version of PowerShell I have

I can provide the output via pastebin if required

Comment: Please include at least the header *in the question itself*, not on a separate site.